# dispatch_async Does Not Run

Tags: ios

I'm new to queues and threading. Below I have the following code that seeks to run various methods within an asynchronous queue. Each item in the queue will update a count when finished, and when all the items are done in the queue, the update count will be complete and ready for return.

The problem is that when this code runs the last line is called and then, it hangs with no errors and I cannot continue to step through the trace.

```
__block int masterUpdateCount = 0;   

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(group);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

   [self updateStuffWithCompletionCount:^(int updatedItemsCount) {
       masterUpdateCount += updatedItemsCount;
   }];

    [self updateMoreStuffWithCompletionCount:^(int updatedItemsCount) {
       masterUpdateCount += updatedItemsCount; // Never gets called
   }];
}); // <------ APPLICATION HANGS HERE after calling dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return masterUpdateCount;
```

Something I noticed is that the completion blocks never get called, which could very well be why it hangs forever, but my question is *why?* If it helps, inside the `updateStuffWithCompletionCount` type methods I'm actually initializing an `NSURLSession` with an `NSURLSessionDataTask` and I am in fact running the task by calling `[task resume];`, so I don't see why the completion wouldn't be called.

Here is what it looks like inside the `updateStuffWithCompletionCount` method:

```
- (void) updateStuffWithCompletionCount: (void (^)(int)) completionResult
{
    __block int updateCount = 0;
    NSString *someURL = @"www.someplace.com";

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * getDataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL someURL] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
      {
          if(error == nil)
          {
              // do stuff, if updated, add to count  

              updateCount ++;

              if(updateCount > 0) {
                  completionResult(updateCount); // Invoke the completion handler
              } else {
                  completionResult(0); // Invoke the completion handler
              }
          }
          else {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              completionResult(-1);
          }
      }];

    [getDataTask resume];
}
```

Hopefully an experienced eye can point it out. Appreciated.

Comment: If you are calling this code on the main thread then you will be blocking the main thread because of the dispatch_group_wait

Comment: Try the update method inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Comment: That will have the same problem because you are still on the main queue. You need to dispatch it on another queue

Comment: Is there anything in `updateStuffWithCompletionCount` that is asynchronous?

Comment: @Paulw11 how can I dispatch it on another queue? I think you're onto something. @Just Another Coder, yes it has a `NSURLSessionDataTask` which I believe is asynchronous.

Comment: You can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{...`

Comment: But I think your approach is inherently flawed - trying to "return" a value from a bunch of asynchronous blocks isn't a good idea.  You need to invoke a block when the tasks are complete rather than returning a value.

Comment: @Paulw11, you're probably right about it being flawed, but it's such a complicated situation, i'm really caught in the mix. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Include code for your dataTask please. This line `masterUpdateCount += updatedItemsCount; // Never gets called` , because its in the completion block which means it doesn't get ran until your datatask is complete, Did you set a breakpoint within your datatask and make sure something its jumping in there? Do you have a NSLog(%@, error.description) line in there in case your getting one? Looks like you may need to do more debugging there.

Comment: It is now included :) . I did set breakpoints within the `getDataTask`, and it does not seem to be jumping in there at all. No error is printed either. It's as though it's being ignored completely despite having the call `[getDataTask resume]`